# The UIViewRoot is null ADF_FACE-30179

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

Did someone already face this problem?

> ADF_FACES-30179**:For more information, please see the server's error log for an entry beginning with: `The UIViewRoot is null`.  Fatal exception during PhaseId: **RESTORE_VIEW 1**.

Unfortunately the log file couldn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Error occurs for at least 2 reasons.

1. One or more errors about EL (Expresive language)
2. Calling a page which no more exists
3. A booken TASK FLOW  bind
4. cpx files not found
5. Binding's file contains paths which are no more activ

Answer (score 2):

One is missing, which was the issue at my Linux system: 
JDeveloper didn't generate the <html> - element,
 instead the <f:view>  component was listed after <!DOCTYPE html> . 
I added it, this resolved my problem.
Edited: this issue went with updating to the current JDeveloper version. Invalid database connection can have this impacts too, interestingly.